# Default executor asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

According to the documentation, when passing `None` to `run_in_executor` the default executor is used:

> awaitable loop.run_in_executor(executor, func, *args) Arrange for func
>   to be called in the specified executor.
>
> The executor argument should be an concurrent.futures.Executor
>   instance. The default executor is used if executor is None.

My question is, what is the default executor of asyncio?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> My question is, what is the default executor of asyncio?

As of this writing (Feb 2020, Python 3.9 alpha), it's a [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) with [default settings](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/925dc7fb1d0db85dc137afa4cd14211bf0d67414/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L808).

Previously one could also call `set_default_executor` to use a different kind of executor, but as of Python 3.8 it's [guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.set_default_executor) to be a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. However, its exact settings aren't documented, so they can change in a future Python release. For example, in Python 3.10 it [sets the `thread_name_prefix` property](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cfb986a1a239f1a00af745a53235b8473b1bd54a/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L821).

Comment: Note that the default settings are [dependent on Python version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=threadpoolexecutor#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor), especially _max_workers_.

Answer (score 5):

You can also take a look at [cpython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/10ac0cded26d91c3468e5e5a87cecad7fc0bcebd/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L809) (assuming thats what you are using)